# Can I keep a trace of aliases in generated XML (or create custom entities)?

Tags: xml, doxygen

I have documented C++ files using Doxygen. Some lines of this documentation have a special meaning for me. These lines need to be processed by an external tool to perform some checks.To do this, I have created doxygen aliases. Then this tool parses the C++ files to extract these lines.

Now, I need to improve this tool to make much more checking (not only on the marked lines). Hence, I will have, instead of using the C++ files, to directly process the XML files generated by Doxygen. Unfortunately generated XML files (at least with the basic configuration) do not keep trace of my aliases. For instance, the alias \nout = \test is converted in:

```
<xrefsect id="test_1_test000001"><xreftitle>Test</xreftitle><xrefdescription>[...]
```

So, what I need, to still be able to identify the specific lines is to obtain a result like:

```
<xrefsect id="..." alias="nout">[...]
```

or to obtain something like

```
<nout><xrefsect id="...">[...]</nout>
```

Does someone know how to configure Doxygen to obtain one of these two solutions (I'am using version 1.7.1)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to keep a trace of my aliases in the XML. For this, I am writing the aliases I need to trace as:

```
aliasName=<span style="visibility:hidden">!aliasName!</span>
```

By this way, in the generated XML I have, somewhere the text !aliasName! that I can easily detect. And, as this text is invisible for HTML it does not appear in the HTML output. It might appear in other output formats, but I do not need them...

Note: I initially tried to write  to be really clean. But the span (or div) marker is totally removed in all cases in the XML.